# vue 3 adapt @mouseover and @mouseleave for touch screens

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, touchscreen

I'm using vue3 js and I have a `@mouseover` and `@mouseleave` to toggle drop-down element. This works as expected on non touch screen devices however it does work on touch screen devices.

How to implement the same behavior on touch screens such that the tap on button behaves like `mouseover` and tap again behaves like `mouseleave`.

I can not use css `:hover` as the `@mouse` code activates and deactivate some css class.

Thanks

Comment: you can use the events and `touchstart`, `touchend`

Comment: @Sysix thanks for response. This partially solves the problem, I have a list of tab buttons with dropdown content which displays when tab is active (@touchstart). For example tab1 has cont1 which displays when tab1 is active, tab2 has cont2 which displays when tab2 is active. When using `touchstart` the solutions works perfectly when you click the same tab to display and hide content however the solution breaks when tab1 is activated and tab2 is activated without deactivating the first active tab, thus there is cont1 and cont2 in display instead of cont2 only.